# Gradle - Package android library with others android librairies inside

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'd like to build an android library and package it as an aar with other sub libraries inside it.

I have a project like this :

sdk

- mainLib
- libA
- libB

I'd like to build mainLib with libA, libB packaged inside mainLib.aar.
This way I can distribute mainLib to users which contain libA and libB.

My mainLib build.grade dependency block looks like the following:

```
      dependencies 

    {   

    compile project(‘:libA:libA-library')   

    compile project(':libB:libB-   library'')     

    }
```

I have tried the above but I see that mainLib aar does not contain libA and libB. Please help.

Comment: Will you distribute the libraries with a maven system?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I use gradle  scripts to build and publish the library aar's to Maven central

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. The MainLib.aar doesn't contain the other aar libraries.

However Maven will manage the right dependencies.

If you will publish in a Maven repo you will see something like this:

**libA.pom**

```
<project>
   <groupId>mygroupID</groupId>
   <artifactId>libA</artifactId>
   <version>X.Y.Z</version>
   <packaging>aar</packaging>
</project>
```

**MainLib.pom**

```
<project>
   <groupId>mygroupID</groupId>
   <artifactId>mainLib</artifactId>
   <version>X.Y.Z</version>
   <packaging>aar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mygroupID</groupId>
      <artifactId>libA</artifactId>
      <version>X.Y.Z</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It means that if someone will use in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'mygroupID:mainLib:X.Y.Z'
}
```

**Gradle will download   the MainLib.aar and all other dependencies.**